# How do I get the number of affected rows when I use DBI's prepare/execute for non-select statement?

Tags: perl, dbi

According to the [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI) documentation, it seems I can only get the number of affected rows by the `do` method.

```
$rows_affected = $dbh->do("UPDATE your_table SET foo = foo + 1");
```

How can I get the same result if I use `prepare`/`execute`?

Comment: execute usually returns the number of rows affected for non-SELECT statements. So in your example it should do. Did you try it? What was the result?

Answer (score 8):

From the documentation about the [`execute` method in DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI#execute):

> For a non-"SELECT" statement, "execute" returns the number of rows
>   affected, if known. If no rows were affected, then "execute" returns
>   "0E0", which Perl will treat as 0 but will regard as true. Note that
>   it is
>              not an error for no rows to be affected by a statement. If
>   the number of rows affected is not known, then "execute" returns -1.

Comment: How do you know whether the statement has syntax error in the first place?

Comment: @R__: `prepare` returns undef.  The DBI docs are admittedly a little less than explicit about this, though they do give the example `$sth = $dbh->prepare($statement)          or die $dbh->errstr;` which hints to this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct any longer, at least in version 4.007. execute is returning the number of *matched* rows, not the number of *affected* rows.

Answer (score 7):

If your query is a **non-SELECT** one (e.g. UPDATE or DELETE), then you can take advantage of [*rows*](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm#rows):

```
my $query = "...";  # your query
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
print "Number of rows affected: " . $sth->rows . "\n";
```

*rows* returns the **number of rows affected** by the last query or **-1** in case of error. However, by design, you cannot rely on *rows* for SELECT statement.

Note that, for non-SELECT queries, also [*execute*](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm#execute) returns the number of rows affected. However, if no row is affected, then *execute* returns *"0E0"* (which Perl should anyway treat as *0*).

```
my $query = "...";  # your query
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
my $numrows = $sth->execute();
print "Number of rows affected: " . $numrows . "\n";
```

If, instead, your query is a **SELECT**, then you cannot rely on *rows*.

However, you can do either:

```
my $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows FROM ... WHERE ...";
my $numrows = $dbh->selectrow_array($query, undef);
print "Number of rows: " . $numrows . "\n";
```

Or, similarly:

```
my $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows FROM ... WHERE ...";
my $numrows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($query, { Slice => {} });
print "Number of rows: " . @$numrows[0]->{rows} . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

As *user153275* said:

> "This doesn't seem to be correct any longer, at least in version 4.007.
>   Execute is returning the number of matched rows, not the number of affected rows."

I found a useful solution in this link, adding the where clause `AND (columnName <> newValue)`:
https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1141381

In this way the query will find only the rows to change.